# Issues with object oriented java code and firebase

Tags: java, firebase, oop, google-cloud-firestore

Cut to the chase:

I've got a class **User**, which holds an instance of **Security**:

```
public class User {
    
    private long id;
    private String name;
    Security security;

    public User(String nname, String password, String userName, String email) {
        this.id = 0;
        this.name = nname;
        this.security = new Security(password, userName, email);
    }

    /**
     * getters and setters
     */
}
```

Yes, the **id** is currently temporary for testing, and **Security** has a very similar format.

Next I run this code for setting up my **firebase entry**:

```
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
this.db = com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.getFirestore(app);
ApiFuture<WriteResult> collectionsApiFuture = 
        db.collection("users").document(user.getName()).set(user);
System.out.println(collectionsApiFuture.get().getUpdateTime().toString());
```

And I use this as my **test data**:

```
FirebaseInitialise testFirebase = new FirebaseInitialise();
User tempUser = new User("Ollie", "123", "OlliesRealm", "email@mail.com");
testFirebase.initialize(tempUser);
```

However, **when I run the code**, the relation appears in the firestore application as:

```
id: 0
name: "Ollie"
security:
    unlocked: true
    userName: "OlliesRealm"
```

I would like it to either properly **hold the full information for security**, which it seems to be unable to do, or to **just hold an ID** of it without actually having the security info stored in user.

If anyone could suggest anything or help me out that would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Based on a cursory reading of the documentation, I suspect that Firebase needs to be told to represent `User.security` as a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to get Security as a full object you just need to save it specifically when uploading on the Firestore database.

```java
@Override
  public String createUser(user user) {
    String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    DocumentReference document = userCollection.document(id);
    Map<String, Object> data = Maps.newHashMap();

    data.put("name", user.getName());
    data.put("security", user.getSecurity());
 
    try {
      document.set(data).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If you want to have them separately you just need to create a different collection for the Security and save it there with something like that:

```java
@Override
  public String createUser(user user) {
    String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    DocumentReference userDocument = userCollection.document(id);
    DocumentReference securityDocument = SecurityCollection.document(id);
    Security temp = user.getSecurity();
    Map<String, Object> userData = Maps.newHashMap();
    Map<String, Object> securityData = Maps.newHashMap();

    userData.put("name", user.getName());
    userData.put("security", user.getSecurity());
    securityData.put("username", security.getUserName());
    securityData.put("password", security.getPassword());
    securityData.put("email", security.getEmail());
 
    try {
      userDocument.set(userData).get();
      securityDocument.set(securityData).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I've moved on from this project, I think my main issue was not actually having basic getters and setters for each attribute- that ended up fixing it. However this is also a really useful answer so thank you very much! Accepted.